# Can't ping over VPN from Virtual Machine in Azure

Tags: networking, vpn, ping, azure

I've setup a VPN connection from Azure to my local network.  I can ping an Azure machine from my local network, but cannot ping a local machine from my Azure network.

I've got the firewall on my Azure machine configured to allow pings from my local network, but I am out of ideas how to get my Azure machine to ping my Local Network.